# Do I install Ubuntu Mate via a USB or do I make the SD card HD a bootable image?

Tags: usb, sd-card, ubuntu

I have a RP 4.  8gb.  My SD card got erased.  So I reinstalled the original boot using Raspberry Pi Imager.  Now I want to use Ubuntu Mate as my OS.  Do I leave the SD card in the RP4 and then have a USB with Ubuntu Mate?  I then turn on the RP4 and it boots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a little lost because I don't know if you mean Raspbian as "the original boot", but I don't think my confusion matters that much.

Since you apparently have not done much with your very-new installation, I would recommend you simply download a new Mate for Pi image from the [ubuntu-mate web site](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/), re-image the SD card, and then enjoy your new Ubuntu Mate Raspberry Pi 4 after you go through the installation steps.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes.  The answer was to 

1) use Raspberry Pi Imager

2) reimage the original SD card with Raspbian

3) Make sure it all works

4) Reimage that same SD card with Ubuntu Mate

5) Load that SD card into RP and set it up